# Partial Cache Members

Tags: silverstripe

I am using the DataObjectsAsPage module. It returns a Datalist ($Items) to the holder page which loops through each $Item. I am also trying to develop a partial caching strategy for the page. I read in the docs that you cannot place cache blocks inside of a loop, so in my DataObjectsAsPageHolder Page, I have the following:

```
<% cached 'items', LastEdited, CacheSegment %>
    <% loop $Items %>
        $Me
    <% end_loop %>
<% end_cached %>
```

I checked the silverstripe-cache/cache directory and this seems to be caching the $Items list.

The problem is that I have added a DataExtension to each $Item that allows the admin to set whether or not an $Item is viewable based on the CurrentMember's group. So within each $Me template I have the following:

```
<% if HasAccess %>
<% end_if %>
```

I have two issues:

1. Given the cache key above, if an authorized member is the first to view a page, then the page gets cached and exclusive material gets shown to non-members in subsequent page views.
2. If I adjust the cache key to the following:

   ```
   <% cached 'items', Items.max(Created), CacheSegment unless CurrentMember %>
       <% loop $Items %>
           $Me
       <% end_loop %>
   <% end_cached %>
   ```

Then the content in each $Me template is never cached for members - which is the largest portion of my sites viewers.

Is there a way I can cache the $Items list for members and non-members and still be able to use the HasAccess check on $Item within the loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution is probably to add the current member's ID to the cache key.

```
<% cached 'items', LastEdited, CacheSegment, CurrentMember.ID %>
    <% loop $Items %>
        $Me
    <% end_loop %>
<% end_cached %>
```

However, this will cache the block uniquely for each registered member. To make the caching a little more useful, you should use the current member's groups in the cache key. Unfortunately, there's no easy way that I know of to get a template cache key ready list of groups for a member.

The easiest way to get a round this issue is probably to add a `GroupsCacheKey` function to your `Page` class. It's a bit of a dirty solution, but it should work effectively.

```
// Untested function
public function GroupsCacheKey() {
    if ($member = Member::currentUser()) {
        return implode('', $member->Groups()->map('ID', 'ID')->toArray());
    }
    return 'nonmember';
}
```

Then in your template:

```
<% cached 'items', LastEdited, CacheSegment, GroupsCacheKey %>
    <% loop $Items %>
        $Me
    <% end_loop %>
<% end_cached %>
```

There is a better solution than this out there somewhere, but it will work.

Comment: The second solution is working great for my situation. The only change needed was to change the asArray method to toArray. Other than that, I have been testing my cached pages and members of similar groups are being served their respective cached pages. Thanks alot for the help!